# Better way to override a function definition

Tags: scala

I'm extending an abstract class from a library, and I want to override a function definition and use the superclass's definition as a fallback.

If the parent class's method were defined as a PartialFunction, I could just use orElse. Since it isn't, I'm doing the thing below (unlifting the parent function into a partial function so I can use orElse). It works, but it is one of those times when I suspect there is a better / more elegant way.  Is there?

```
abstract class ThingICantChange {
    def test:Int=>String = {
      case 1 => "one"
      case 2 => "two"
      case _ => "unknown"
    }
}

class MyClass extends ThingICantChange {
  def myChanges:PartialFunction[Int,String] = {
    case 2 => "mytwo"
    case 3 => "three"
  }
  override def test = myChanges orElse Function.unlift(x => Some(super.test(x)))
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would do this:

```
class MyClass extends ThingICantChange {
  override def test: Int => String = {
    case 2 => "mytwo"
    case 3 => "three"
    case x => super.test(x)
  } 
}
```

If you're looking to construct a partial function from `super.test` then here's a clean way:

```
override def test = myChanges orElse PartialFunction(super.test)
```

Comment: Yes ... I should have clarified: my code is more complicated than this (obviously), and I'd like to be able to compose multiple partial functions using orElse. I could just make a default `def last:PartialFunction[Int,String] = { case x => super.test(x) }` and use that as the final orElse, but that doesn't seem to be better than what I did. I just had a feeling that there was an equivalent of my `Function.unlift(x => Some(super.test(x)))` silliness that I hadn't learned yet.

Comment: Updated my answer to reflect your goal.

Comment: You see, I knew there must be a simpler way! Can't believe I didn't think of that. Thanks.